# Create synchronizedList from within spring xml file

Tags: spring, arraylist, synchronized

The collection framework has Synchronization Wrappers that help create synchronized lists.

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

I am trying to create the list from the spring xml file. Following works fine for a simple List.

```
<bean id="listt" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
```

Is there anyway i can directly create a synchronizedList from within the xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct using `Collections.synchronizedList` as a [static factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method):

```
<bean id="list" class="java.util.Collections" factory-method="synchronizedList">
  <constructor-arg><bean class="java.util.ArrayList"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```